# Convention for the derivative of a diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Simple question: $A$ is an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix: $$A = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} a_{11} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & a_{22} & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & a_{nn} \end{array}\right)$$
How is the derivative of $A$ wrt to the diagonal components $\mathrm dA/\mathrm da$ defined? Is it: $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \end{array}\right),$$ i.e. the $n\times n$ identity matrix, or: $$\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{array}\right)$$
(equivalently, as row vector).

Comment: If $a$ is a vector and $A(a)$ is a matrix, then by the usual conventions $\frac{dA}{da}$ is an order $3$ tensor

Comment: I am confused; I have $A = \mathrm{Diag}(a)$ and want to take the derivative wrt to $a$. How is that different from taking the derivative of $A$ wrt $A$ (since the off diagonal elements are 0) which is $I$?

Comment: You have a function whose input is an $n$-vector and whose output is a $n \times n$ matrix. For each entry in the matrix-valued output there is a gradient vector. Hence, there are $n^3$ derivatives in total, which is why you need a $n \times n \times n$ "matrix". Yes, many of those derivatives are equal to the zero function.

Comment: thank you, I think I see the point. If the setting was a little different and $A = \mathrm{Diag}(a(s))$ for some parameter $s$ and I would take the derivative wrt $s$, would I get $n\times n$ matrix or a vector?

Comment: If $s$ is a _scalar_ parameter, then  $\frac{dA}{ds}$ will be a matrix and $\frac{da}{ds}$ will be a vector.